# JSON Adding to file problem. Only Object Object appears

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-maps, object

So i try to post a new node to a json file.

Here is my js:

```
        var newDate = new Date;             
        var markerId = newDate.getTime();
        var markerData = { 'id': markerId, 'lat':markerId, 'long':markerId };


        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',
            url: "dataPath.php",
            data: {
                    marker: markerData
                },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            success: function(result)
                {
                    alert("Added OK");
                }               
        });
```

And here is the php file

```
$dataPath = 'file_path';
$markerDataFile = 'adauga.json';
$markerText = file_get_contents($markerDataFile);
$markerList = json_decode($markerText,true);
 if( !empty($_POST['marker'])  ){

    $markerData =  $_POST['marker'];
    $markerData['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $markerData['created'] = time();
    $markerList['markers'][] = $markerData;
    $markerText = json_encode($markerList);
    file_put_contents($markerDataFile, $markerText);
    echo json_encode($markerData);
}else{
    echo "Invalid request";
```

The problem is the JSON file displays this:

```
{"markers":[{"id":"1310499027672","lat":"47.1405","long":"7.243839999999977","ip":"127.0.0.1","created":1310499032},"1object Object]","1object Object]","1object Object]","1object Object]","1object Object]","1object Object]","1object Object]","1object Object]"]}
```

Comment: The code you've posted works for me. It's possible that the error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `$markerData` has additional nested objects that need to be read explicitly and added to the json explicitly. You need to target those objects' properties and add them one by one.

If you were to echo `$_POST['marker']` you would get `[object Object]` but if you print it like this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST['marker']);
echo "</pre>";
```

Then you will see all of markers objects and properties and you can add them individually to your json or at least reference them in a for loop.

Comment: `json_encode()` if perfectly capable of dealing with objects and nested arrays. You can only get `[object Object]` if you cast an object to string in *JavaScript*.